# LM324 for 10,000x gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm looking to use the LM324n (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) single-supply op-amp in non-inverting mode:

[image]

The goal is to take a voltage of around 100uV and multiply it to around 1V (i.e. let R1 = 100 ohms, and let R2 = 1 megohm), while supplying the op amp with +5V on one end and GND on the other end.

Will this work?

Comment: Is the input voltage AC or DC?

Comment: DC. Any solutions then?

Comment: Yes. Chopper stabilised amplifier.

Comment: Are you sure your SNR of the input won't be around like zero?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The op-amp is configured as an inverter and, with +100uV on the input, the output will try to go negative but it can't because you restricted the negative power rail to 0V. So this means your source has to have a negative voltage fed to the input (a possible constraint).

The trouble with the LM324 is the input offset voltage is about 2mV i.e. about 20 times bigger than the signal and this may well be a positive offset and, as said above will force the op-amp output to go negative.

If it's a negative offset then 2mV x 10,000 = 20V and the op-amp is saturated hard against the positive rail (or as near as it can get to it i.e. about +3V).

Also, when running from a 5V supply, input bias currents could be as high as 500nA (across temperature). This will flow thru the 100 ohm input resistor and create an offset of 50uV - that's half your signal.

Stop this madness and use a proper op-amp suitable for the job like an [ADA4528](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf). It has input bias currents of <1nA and an input offset voltage of about 4 uV. It is also a rail-to rail device on inputs and outputs.

Comment: I think using a single op-amp is not realistic in this scenario (you also have to consider bandwidth).  I think two stages is the best option

Comment: @crocboy Yeah I read that in your answer but you are missing the point about input offset voltages swamping the thing.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about that, good point

Comment: Okay what should I be looking for then? is a chopper stabilized amplifier very expensive?

Comment: @Dave see my edit for a typical device recommendation off the top of my head. If this is too expensive focus on the parameters mentioned and have a good scout around. If you pick something come back and ask a new question maybe.

Comment: Good recommendation on the ADA4528, which hides its chopper stabilization quite well...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I know it's nerdy to say but it's my favourite op-amp in low/medium GBP ;)

Comment: @Dave - You can use an op amp with a large offset voltage, as long as you add an offset adjust to get rid of it. THEN you have to worry about offset stability, in this case offset temperature coefficient. For an LM324, this can be as high as 30 uV / degree C, so a 3 degree drift would give a full-scale error. So take Andyaka's advice and get a better op amp.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast good call on the drift dude

Answer (score 4):

Since there are a lot of answers already about why that particular part is not suitable, I'm going to mention a few more issues that apply in general, for any opamp:

- Unless spec'ed specifically, most opamps don't like their inputs to go all the way to the supply rails, so either use a slight negative supply for the opamp or bring the reference up a bit using a voltage divider or zener reference.
- That much gain will probably give you a lot of noise from several sources:

  - Ambient noise present in the original signal.
  - Johnson (thermal) noise in the 1M resistor.
  - Equivalent noise of the opamp itself.
- If you want to amplify DC, then it's going to be nightmarishly sensitive to calibrate.  Until you get the reference level just right, it'll be stuck high or stuck low all the time.  If you don't need DC, then put a capacitor in series with the input to remove it automatically.
- You said you wanted non-inverting, but your schematic is inverting.  Which do you actually want?

I'd be tempted to cascade several lower-gain stages instead, mostly for the thermal noise performance because it allows lower resistances and therefore less noise.  Basically, you have electrons jiggling around in there because heat does that to everything, but electrons moving equals current, which equals voltage across a resistor.

Comment: Having multiple stages to reduce input noise sources (such as En or feedback resistor noise) makes things worse. This is why photodiode TIAs try and get as much gain out of the 1st stage as possible. They limit the maximum feedback resistance ONLY because the bandwidth is falling off (then they use a lower than optimum value resistor and a 2nd gain stage.)

Comment: @Andyaka: Hmm, okay.  So...En and resistor noise from each stage becomes ambient noise to the next, so that's a motivation to have lower gain later, with the ultimate example being a string of unity-gain buffers that might as well be removed.  But the added noise of the first stage increases more slowly as it does a larger portion of the work?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely.

Input offset voltage of 2 mV (typ) means that with no input the output could be anywhere from -0.2 to +0.2 V. If you're using it single-supply, that means you won' see any output.

Given your actual input is only 100 uV, your signal will be swamped by offset voltage effects.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your circuit is an inverting amplifier.  Of course it will work (assuming you have the correct power supplies set up), but with such a high gain, you will have a very small bandwidth.  Gain-bandwidth product of LM324 is 1 MHZ.

1 MHz / 10,000 = 100 Hz.  If you want a high gain with a better bandwidth, I would recommend using two stages, each with a gain of 100.

Comment: The input offset is most likely going to be a bigger problem than the GBW product.